# PowerShell: Cannot insert GUID

Tags: powershell, guid, uniqueidentifier

I am trying to insert data from a csv file into a table in SQL Server where one of the columns in the table is of the data type of uniqueidentifier

The data in the csv file is a guid, I can copy and paste the guid into the uniqueidentifier column, so the data is valid, but when I try and load the data via powershell I get the following error

Write-SqlTableData : The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type uniqueidentifier of the specified target column.

The following is my failed attempt to load the data.

```
$rows = Import-Csv -Path $csv
$rows | Select-Object string,

    @{name="GUID";expression={ [string]$_.String }},
    @{name="Company";expression={ [string]$_.String }},
    @{name="Modified";expression={ [datetime]$_.DateTime }}

$rows | Write-SqlTableData ....
```

If anyone can help point me in the right direction would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to cast the data type to `[guid]` before writing it.

If your csv looks like this for example:

```
GUID,Company,Modified
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000,CorpA,2022-10-10
11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111,CorpB,2022-11-11
etc...
```

Then you should be able to convert the csv input to guid like so:

```
$rows = Import-Csv -Path $csv |
  Select-Object @{n="GUID";e={[guid]$_.GUID}},
    Company,
    @{n="DateTime";e={[DateTime]$_.DateTime}}

$rows | Write-SqlTableData ....
```

---

If you also *generated* your CSV with powershell, then you might prefer the `Export-Clixml` and `Import-Clixml` commands, since they will keep data types intact instead of converting to string